# Longest increasing subsequence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, rust

I'm just getting into Rust, and I've decided to implement the longest increasing subsequence algorithm suggested in the related [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). Though this program compiles and returns the expected sequence for what's passed to `lis`, I am wondering if more experienced Rust programmers would have written this same algorithm in a different way?

```
 fn lis(x: Vec<i32>)-> Vec<i32> {
    let n = x.len();
    let mut m = vec![0; n];
    let mut p = vec![0; n];
    let mut l = 0;

    for i in 0..n {
        let mut lo = 1;
        let mut hi = l;

        while lo <= hi {
            let mut mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

            if x[m[mid]] <= x[i] {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        let mut new_l = lo;
        p[i] = m[new_l - 1];
        m[new_l] = i;

        if new_l > l {
            l = new_l;
        }
    }

    let mut o = vec![0; l];
    let mut k = m[l];
    for i in (0..l).rev() {
        o[i] = x[k];
        k    = p[k];
    }

    o
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15];
    let o = lis(v);
    println!("{:?}", o);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The parameter `x` doesn't have to be a `Vec`, it could be a slice instead (`&[i32]`). However, if you had used a non-`Copy` item type (`i32` is `Copy`), then in order to return individual items from the input `Vec`, you'd either have to [`clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) the items or move them out of the `Vec` (using [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove)).
2. You've implemented binary search by hand, but the Rust standard library provides a very flexible implementation via [`slice::binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by).

I present you my own implementation of the algorithm, based on a [slightly different C++ implementation](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php?title=Longest_Increasing_Subsequence.cpp&oldid=13595), which is why there are so many differences compared to your version. I wrote this about one year ago, but sadly, I no longer use it. Note a few things though that are not necessarily relevant to the code review:

1. This is a very generic function: the `selector` parameter is used to extract a particular field from each item in the slice. I was using this function on a slice of objects and I was interested in finding increasing values of a particular field of these objects.
2. The function returns *indices* into the slice, not the values themselves. I needed to know the indices of the items in the longest increasing subsequence because I had to do something else with the items that were not in the subsequence (without destroying the original sequence), and using indices was the easiest way to do that. If I wanted to return the values without consuming the original sequence, I could have returned a `Vec` of references to the items instead (`Vec<&T>`).
3. Single letter variable names don't really help to understand the algorithm. Since I was using this algorithm for practical purposes, I took the time to understand and document it. If this is just an exercise to learn idiomatic Rust, I suppose this kind of detail doesn't matter much.
4. I like your use of a `for` loop on a reversed range iterator at the end. I should have done that myself!

```
/// Finds one of the [longest increasing subsequences][1]
/// from the subsequence created by applying `selector` on each item in `items`.
/// The result is a vector of indices within `items`
/// corresponding to one of the longest increasing subsequences.
///
/// [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence
pub fn lis<T, I: Ord, F: Fn(&T) -> I>(items: &[T], selector: F) -> Vec<usize> {
    // This algorithm is adapted from
    // http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php?title=Longest_Increasing_Subsequence.cpp&oldid=13595

    let mut result = Vec::new();

    // If `items` is empty, then the result is also empty.
    if items.is_empty() {
        return result;
    }

    // This vector stores, for each item,
    // the index of the largest item prior to itself that is smaller than itself.
    // We'll use this vector at the end to build the final result.
    let mut previous_chain = vec![0; items.len()];

    // Initially, we assume that the first item is part of the result.
    // We will replace this index later if that's not the case.
    result.push(0);

    for i in 1..items.len() {
        // If the next item is greater than the last item of the current longest subsequence,
        // push its index at the end of the result and continue.
        if selector(&items[*result.last().unwrap()]) < selector(&items[i]) {
            previous_chain[i] = *result.last().unwrap();
            result.push(i);
            continue;
        }

        // Perform a binary search to find the index of an item in `result` to overwrite.
        // We want to overwrite an index that refers to the smallest item that is larger than `items[i]`.
        // If there is no such item, then we do nothing.
        let comparator = |&result_index| {
            use std::cmp::Ordering;

            // We don't return Ordering::Equal when we find an equal value,
            // because we want to find the index of the first equal value.
            if selector(&items[result_index]) < selector(&items[i]) {
                Ordering::Less
            } else {
                Ordering::Greater
            }
        };

        let next_element_index = match result.binary_search_by(comparator) {
            Ok(index) | Err(index) => index,
        };

        if selector(&items[i]) < selector(&items[result[next_element_index]]) {
            if next_element_index > 0 {
                previous_chain[i] = result[next_element_index - 1];
            }

            result[next_element_index] = i;
        }
    }

    // The last item in `result` is correct,
    // but we might have started overwriting earlier items
    // with what could have been a longer subsequence.
    // Walk back `previous_chain` to restore the proper subsequence.
    let mut u = result.len();
    let mut v = *result.last().unwrap();
    while u != 0 {
        u -= 1;
        result[u] = v;
        v = previous_chain[v];
    }

    result
}
```